# How to assign specific channel to empty interface channel

Tags: go, rabbitmq

If I had an empty interface channel type that I just wanted to watch for events, and wanted to assign specific channels to it as the flow needed, is that possible in Golang?

```
myChan := make(chan interface{})
confirms := ch.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))
myChan = confirms // (<- cannot use type chan Confirmation in type chan interface{} assignment
```

Comment: You do not have a generic channel type, because go currently has no generics. `chan interface{}` and `chan amqp.Confirmation` are distinct types.

Comment: But the empty interface is an approximation of generic type.  If I create chan interface{}, I can transmit string, ints, or other types and use a switch to handle the output.  If channels can act with type agnostic behavior, it seemed as if there would be a way to create a type agnostic channel and assign other channels to it.

Comment: Go types are invariant, so it doesn't matter if you try to vaguely define interfaces as "an approximation of generic type", `chan A` and `chan B` are different (it may not be clear, but `interface{}` is no different functionally than any other interface, it simply has no methods).

Comment: Assuming this code would compile, how do you expect `myChan <- "foo"` to work? In particular, what would a receiver of confirms see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the channel itself as an empty interface, then resolve it at the other end.

```
confirms := ch.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))
var mychanpointerpointer interface{}
mychanpointerpointer = confirms
.
.
.
switch mychanpointer := mychanpointerpointer.(type) {
case chan amqp.Confirmation:
    fmt.Println("GOT A CONFIRMATION CHANNEL:", mychanpointer)
}
```

Output: `GOT A CONFIRMATION CHANNEL: 0xc42016a000`

Comment: This isn't actually a "chatroom": the questions and answers on StackOverflow are supposed to be preserved for eternity (or at least a few decades) to make a community-built FAQ, of sorts. So wording really matters here. Generics and interfaces are different: see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7224675/1256452). (I didn't downvote myself, but if you update your Q-and-self-A to use the right words, that might help...)

Comment: @ArloGuthrie, from where I stand, it looks that the `go` community here is not obsessed with answering questions which should probably not have been asked if the poster did read at least the official FAQ and may be a couple of entry-level docs on the matter. So yes, there exists certain culture of rushing to SO instead of reading the docs and the culture of answering such questions to get karma (or whatever that number is called in SO's parlance). Folks reading the `go` tag just seem to not belong to the group of people fond of both these cultures.

Comment: @ArloGuthrie, to maybe better highlight what I mean, I once jokingly answered a question «how to log first N commits in Git?», but now it is the highest upvoted answer among all the answers I gave on SO. And that is the answer to a question which can be answered by looking at the output of `git log --help` for, I dunno, fifteen seconds. I mean, that sick culture of not willing to do one's own research is reinforced by another culture of pumping up karma by answering those questions. You can see that backfiring in our case—just in a bit unexpected form may be ;-)

Comment: @Kostix I asked how to pass a generic type channel when I should have asked how to pass a channel and treat it generically using empty interface / switch / reflection.  I think some people saw the word "generic" and quit reading.  :D